# Comments tabbing to the wrong button

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface

Some times* when I am commenting on a question (post?) and hit tab and space/enter, it sets focus to the "Post Answer" button, sending an empty answer and erasing my comment.

Can we:

1. Check on the client side if the post body is empty, so it doesn't get submit?
2. Have the tab work correctly?

* I don't know exactly how to reproduce it, but it happens from time to time. I am Chrome/Ubuntu

Comment: Probably related to this, which is apparently fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/tabbing-after-editing-a-comment-incorrectly-sets-focus-on-add-comment-button-in

Answer (score 1):

This appears to only happen if you are holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In which case, I don't know how well it could be fixed in the system.

Note that if you have already provided an answer, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will navigate you to the Search bar instead of the "Add Another Answer" button. Which is probably worse, actually.